# Processing stuck at "Waiting for device" while trying to connect to emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, processing

I am using Processing to program an app for Android. While trying to run an example on the emulator started through the AVD manager, Processing window hangs at "Trying to connect to device..." and finally gives up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to follow the suggestion at:

http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/processing-cant-get-connected-to-phone-emulator-need-help.html

To paraphrase:

Open "preferences.txt" and change the port number in

android.emulator.port=xxxx

to the one shown at the head of the emulator window.

If this line is not there in preferences.txt, just add it. For me preferences.txt was located at ~/.processing/preferences.txt. You can locate yours by clicking File->Preferences. It is mentioned at the bottom of the window.